# How can I add another animation to what I've already done?

Tags: animation, mesh, smoke-simulation, fire

I made a simple animation of a mesh crumpling (while not as good looking as a piece of paper, it'll do) and I want to set it on fire when it reaches the end of the animation (crumpled ball). I tried looking up explosions but that seems to have a similar effect with vastly more difficult results. I don't want to have it on fire the whole time, just when it reaches the crumpled ball phase. I am a beginner. I've watched some videos and tried to add the fire+smoke to my mesh but it turned it to a wire frame and I'm not even seeing the Fire+smoke.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you watch a tutorial for the version of blender you are using, 2.8+ changed up a lot and older tutorials might not work right or be hard to follow. Also when you do get your sim working you should be able to keyframe certain aspects of your fire+smoke emitter to make it look like it catches rather than constantly burning.